# Find $f$ from $f'$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $f'(z)$ exists on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Im(f'(z))=6x(2y-1)$. Find $f$.

I used the fact that we can use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. So if $f(x,y)=u+iv$, I obtain $u=6x^2+6y-6y^2+c$. From this information, how could I get $f$. I think we have to "integrating" $f'$, but I don't know how because $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Hint : Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: I obtain $f'(x,y)=(6x^2+6y-6y^2+c)+i(6x(2y-1))$ from the Cauchy-Riemann equations. How this last theorem could help me to find $f$ from $f'$?

Comment: Try to write $f'$ as a function of $z$. It will be a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you mean with $x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ and $y=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$?

Comment: If need be, you can do it thus. You should however recognise the real and imaginary parts of $z$ and $z^2$ and from that assemble the function with less work.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that... Instead of being a function of $x$ and $y$, we are function of $z$ and $\bar{z}$. Are you certain of what you are telling me?

Comment: I am certain. What is $\operatorname{Re} z^2$? (With $z = x+iy$ of course.)

Comment: @DanielFischer So I obtain $(6(z^2+\bar{z}^2)-3i(z-\bar{z}))+(-3i((z^2-\bar{z}^2)i+(z+\bar{z})))=9z^2 +3\bar{z}-i6z$. Could you tell me the next step, because I don't see it?

Comment: You _should_ obtain $f'(z) = 6z^2 - 6iz + c$, where $c$ is a real constant. You must have miscalculated somewhere. With $f'(z) = 6z^2 - 6iz + c$, it shouldn't be hard to find $f(z)$.

Comment: What is the advantage of using this method, then we can use Cauchy-Riemann?

Comment: You look at $\operatorname{Im} \bigl(f'(z)\bigr) = 6\cdot (2xy - x)$. If you can _see_ that $2xy = \operatorname{Im} z^2$ and $x = \operatorname{Im} iz$, you don't need to calculate to see $\operatorname{Im} \bigl(f'(z)\bigr) = \operatorname{Im} (6z^2 - 6iz)$ and thus $f'(z) = 6z^2 - 6iz + c$ for an unknown real $c$. If you can see these things, that saves you work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Riemann equations you get something like this, I think
$$f '(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)-iu_y(x,y)$$
From here, you can get the answer
$$f(z)=f(x,y)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$